# AlphaSSL - "CA Bundle does not match the certificate" - in CPanel

Tags: ssl, certificate, bundle, cpanel, ca

I have received a wildcard certificate from AlphaSSL.

The CSR was generated in CPanel. The SSL CRT is being accepted in the SSL manager console for CPanel.

As Android and some other devices do not validate the SSL certificate on it's own, it needs further addition of the CA Bundle / Intermediate Root Certificate to the server.

The intermediate certificate was supplied in the confirmation email, but fails to install to the server.

When I paste this into the CA Bundle field, it states the "The CA Bundle does not match the certificate".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that AlphaSSL & Globalsign made a major update to their intermediate root certificates as of the 31st March 2014 (last week).

A lot of SSL resellers have not yet updated confirmation emails, and are providing outdated intermediate root certificates (last updated in 2011) which will not work.

Also in a lot of support web pages, references are made to these same old certificates.

Hopefully resellers will update their systems in coming weeks/months.

However should anyone else have problems with this, you can get the latest Root Certificates directly from the following links...

AlphaSSL :
http://www.alphassl.com/support/install-root-certificate.html

Globalsign :
https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1426602-globalsign-root-certificates

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the CA Bundle text and run installation. Because In most cases, you do not need to supply the CA bundle because the server will fetch it from a public repository during installation.

Comment: Works for me using acme.sh. Thanks!